# Unable to upload files > 50MB to SharePoint 2013 in Chrome Only

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have found an issue on our SharePoint 2013 farm where files >50MB in size cannot be uploaded to a document library using Chrome. The same files in IE10 upload without a problem.

When uploading, we receive the following error:

```
"Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred."
```

In ULS we can see the following:

```
Application error when access /xxx/xxxxxxx/_layouts/15/UploadEx.aspx, 
Error=Maximum request length exceeded.  
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()    
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent()    
at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()    
at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm()    
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.IsSignInResponse(HttpRequest request)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsSignInResponse(HttpRequest request)    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CanReadSignInResponse(HttpRequest request, Boolean onPage)    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)    
at   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

We have checked the following and have been left scratching our heads:

1. The maximum upload size has been set in the Web Application to 2GB
2. The 2GB limit is reflected in the web.config file
3. It affects all document types we have tested
4. We have tested against multiple users, on multiple machines against multiple site collections
5. Files less than 50MB will upload through Chrome as expected
6. IE will upload the same file without error

Due to the number of users, at the moment it would require a pretty good business case to move everyone to a later version of Chrome. Due to this I was wondering if anyone might have any thoughts?

Many Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

OK, so finally found an answer to this, and it is a bug within Chrome v27.

On a test machine we upgraded to version 28 and the uploads proceeded as expected without any further amendments.

Unable to find anything online to document this however, it appears as though it is resolved by a Chrome update.

Comment: Hi Ade, I'm wondering if you're still having this issue? I'm running into it myself in our environment. However, I'm all the way up on version 63.